# Sound on youtube embed api

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to put an embed youtube video on a website but with littles tweaks.
I don't want the video to have the youtube overlay and i want it to play automatically.
I Have this:

```
<iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YourVideoId?autoplay=1&loop=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

That works fine. Well in a certain way. As I understood there is no way with this method to set a volume to the video. Because for now the video starts with the volume at its maximum and this is pretty anoying.
So I took a look at the javascript API:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en, and with that one i managed to set the volume. But only the volume.
According to the documentation there is a way to manipulate the IFrame object in the same way as if it was generated with the javascript API (logical in fact).

But the point is , I can figure out How to do it.
If someone as any idea how to do it let me know , i'd really like to know how to dit it.

Thanks

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562488/youtube-player-doesnt-recognize-embedded-youtube-video

Comment: You said you weren't able to set the volume. Then you were able to fix it by using the iframe youtube api. Now what's the problem?